# update multiple rows in mysqli table base on two values

Tags: mysql

I know this is an old question that is repeated here a lot. 
but I couldn't find an answer that works, and my code is really bad. 
How can i update multiple rows in one query when i have to use two keys to run through in my query.
I saw a lot of answers. But no one worked for me.

my table:

```
id| entry  | meta_key | meta_value
1 |    1   |     2    |   input1
2 |    1   |     3    |   input2
3 |    1   |     4    |   input3
4 |    2   |     5    |   input4
```

i'm updating the table using the entry as an id. but the code is repetitive.
the only pice of data that is fixed is the meta_key. and will not change.

```
$result = $wpdb->query("UPDATE `table_name` SET `meta_value`= '".$meta_value1."' WHERE `entry` = '".$entry."'  AND `meta_key` = 2");
$result = $wpdb->query("UPDATE `table_name` SET `meta_value`= '".$meta_value2."' WHERE `entry` = '".$entry."'  AND `meta_key` = 3");
```

how can i make this code good.

P.S 
my code works

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8388192

Comment: thanks. that worked